# SQL Query to Select Latest Version for Different Column Combinations

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

| Product | ImageVersion | ImageName | ImageBinary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gizmo | 1 | Green | 0x45679ABC |
| Gizmo | 1 | Blue | 0x5679ABCD |
| Gizmo | 1 | Red | 0x679ABCDE |
| Widget | 1 | Green | 0x01234567 |
| Widget | 1 | Blue | 0x12345678 |
| Widget | 1 | Red | 0x23456789 |
| Widget | 2 | Red | 0x345679AB |

I would like to get the latest ImageBinary for a given Product and ImageName

I have a query that is close. A, B, and C return the desired ImageBinary. D returns nothing. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
-- A
SELECT a.ImageBinary
FROM [Database].[dbo].[DataTable] a
LEFT JOIN [Database].[dbo].[DataTable] b 
ON a.ImageName = b.ImageName AND a.ImageVersion < b.ImageVersion 
WHERE b.ImageVersion Is NULL AND a.ImageName = 'Green' AND a.Product = 'Widget'

-- B
SELECT a.ImageBinary
FROM [Database].[dbo].[DataTable] a
LEFT JOIN [Database].[dbo].[DataTable] b 
ON a.ImageName = b.ImageName AND a.ImageVersion < b.ImageVersion 
WHERE b.ImageVersion Is NULL AND a.ImageName = 'Green' AND a.Product = 'Gizmo'

-- C
SELECT a.ImageBinary
FROM [Database].[dbo].[DataTable] a
LEFT JOIN [Database].[dbo].[DataTable] b 
ON a.ImageName = b.ImageName AND a.ImageVersion < b.ImageVersion 
WHERE b.ImageVersion Is NULL AND a.ImageName = 'Red' AND a.Product = 'Widget'

-- D
SELECT a.ImageBinary
FROM [Database].[dbo].[DataTable] a
LEFT JOIN [Database].[dbo].[DataTable] b 
ON a.ImageName = b.ImageName AND a.ImageVersion < b.ImageVersion 
WHERE b.ImageVersion Is NULL AND a.ImageName = 'Red' AND a.Product = 'Gizmo'

===================================

USE [Database]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DataTable](
    [Product] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [ImageVersion] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ImageName] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [ImageBinary] [varchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DataTable_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Product] ASC,
    [ImageVersion] ASC,
    [ImageName] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: I realized I need to use a table with on <Product> before the join, then discovered queries can be joined. This works:

Comment: SELECT  Q1.ImageBinary FROM 
(
SELECT  t.Product,  t.ImageVersion,  t.ImageName,  t.ImageBinary
FROM [Database].[dbo].[DataTable] t
WHERE t.Product = '<PRODUCT NAME>'
) Q1
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT  t.Product,  t.ImageVersion,  t.ImageName,  t.ImageBinary
FROM [Database].[dbo].[DataTable] t
WHERE t.Product = '<PRODUCT NAME>'
) Q2 
ON Q1.ImageName = Q2.ImageName AND Q1.ImageVersion < Q2.ImageVersion 
WHERE Q2.ImageVersion Is NULL AND Q1.ImageName = '<IMAGE NAME>' AND Q1.Product = '<PRODUCT NAME>'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify the rows you want. Then filtering out the other ones is easy. For example:

```
select *
from (
  select t.*,
    row_number() over(partition by product order by imagename desc) as rn
  from [Database].[dbo].[DataTable] t
) x
where rn = 1
```

Comment: I won't know the row number ahead of time. The selection needs to be the highest numbered ImageVersion for a given Product and ImageName.

Comment: @CodeRed2550000 It's sorted descending so you just take `rn = 1` always

Comment: @TheImpaler I think it should be `partition by product, imagename order by...`

Comment: @CodeRed2550000 `ROW_NUMBER()`  is a function that produces serial numbers starting from 1 according to each grouping and ordering. Then, it's a matter of taking all the 1s.